# Simple HTTP server failing with "connection redefined"

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio

Based on boost's examples I wrote the following program. It should answer connections with a HTTP 200 and a small text:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 40001));
        while (true)
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            //Aceitou uma conexao
            time_t now = time(0);
            stringstream ssHtml;
            ssHtml << "HELLO WORLD ";
            stringstream ssHttp;
            ssHttp << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
            ssHttp << "Connection: close\r\n";
            ssHttp << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
            ssHttp << "Content-Length: " << ssHtml.str().size() <<"\r\n";
            ssHttp << ssHtml.str();
            ssHttp << "\r\n\r\n";
            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            cout << ssHttp.str();
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(ssHttp.str()), ignored_error);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the browser's request fails with "connection redefined". When debugging the server I saw that it successfully runs, printing the http response to it's console.

In firefox's devloper mode I saw that the response arrives but for some reason the browser says that the connection has been redefined. For some reason, the browser connects twice at the server and fails both times.
Also, the firewall is open and the port is free.

My question is: what am I doing wrong? Why is this simple server not answering the request? Why is the browser failing with a "connection redefined" error?

Comment: Two issues i noticed: The last header ("Content-length") should end with 2 line breaks, marking the end of the headers, the 2 line breaks after the content are not needed; and second: you probably should also read the request from browser.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP protocol requires a double line-end to mark the end of the response headers. At least add the one:

```
        ssHttp << "\r\n" << ssHtml.str();
```

And, you will probably want to avoid sending the extraneous line-end following the content data too (although with a `Connection: close` header the difference should not be very noticeable).

Answer (score 0):

When I read the request from the browser, as ChrisBFX suggested in a comment above, my server worked more or less as intended. The response was sent the browser and the browser understood it. It still sends two responses instead of one but it is no longer failing with "connection redirected".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 40001));
        while (true)
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
/////////////-------------THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM----------------------
            boost::asio::streambuf s_buf;
            boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, s_buf, "\r\n\r\n",
                std::bind([](const boost::system::error_code& ec){
                if (ec != 0)
                    std::cout << "error " << ec.value() << ", " << ec.message();
                }, 
                std::placeholders::_1));
            std::string message;
            std::istream input_stream(&s_buf);
            std::getline(input_stream, message);
            std::cout << message << std::endl;
///////////////------------------------------------------------------
            time_t now = time(0);
            stringstream ssHtml;
            ssHtml << "HELLO WORLD ";
            stringstream ssHttp;
            ssHttp << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
            ssHttp << "Connection: close\r\n";
            ssHttp << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
            ssHttp << "Content-Length: " << ssHtml.str().size();// << "\r\n";
            ssHttp << "\r\n\r\n";
            ssHttp << ssHtml.str();         
            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            cout << ssHttp.str();
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(ssHttp.str()), ignored_error);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```